# Access/Update data in server from android app using Web API provided by web developer?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Let us say I work for a company which is building a dynamic web application. I am the android developer. I have been asked to develop a native android app for the web application. The web app developers have provided me the API to access the data using JSON. I develop my android app using Volley to get dynamic data from the website and also post data from my android app which updates the database and therefore can be viewed by users who access the website from any browser.

The following are my questions:

1. Is my understanding of the above scenario conceptually correct. If not, please clarify?
2. Is there any other way I can access/update data other than provided web API's?
3. Will I be using the web developer provided API to get data from server and also update data from the server? Does it work both ways. For example posting data on Facebook.
4. Do I need to know any web programming in addition to access/update data using developer provided APIs? (I do not want to learn how to create web applications in addition to creating android applications at least at this time).
5. I believe if I am asked to develop a hybrid android app using Cordova/Ionic, I would be accessing/updating data using my javascript builtin functions(not sure which one at this time) and pass my HTML, CSS and JavaScript to Ionic to wrap my app for a specific platform. Is my understanding accurate?

Thank you for your response in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samuel has basically answered all your questions but I would like to add few more things.

Ionic is a front-end mobile development SDK that heavily uses AngularJS in addition to HTML and CSS. Therefore, your knowledge of Angular highly correlates with application development using ionic. Note that there are 2 versions of Ionic, namely [ionic 1](http://ionicframework.com/) and [ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/). Ionic 2 seems to be the future of Ionic since it is based on Angular 2. Since you are still in planning phase, I would recommend going with Ionic 2 for long term success.

Furthermore, using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) is something that you will encounter (should anticipate) soon as an Ionic developer.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have not decided with Ionic at this time. I am also not keen on learning AngularJS additionally. At this time, I just want to leverage my HTML, CSS and JavaScript skills in building a hybrid android app. Having said that, I also want to be current with technology. 1. Is there any other framework you could suggest other than Ionic which can help me leverage my existing skills. 2. Can I just use JavaScript with Ionic 2?

Comment: @SrikanthGanesan  1: You could use bare Cordova if you want to get started with basic HTML, CSS and JS. It does not require any knowledge of AngularJS. 2: Ionic 2 is written in TypeScript which gets transpiled to JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks again for your response! Do companies widely use bare Cordova (or) I have to eventually shift to Ionic?

Comment: Many companies use cordova/ionic in order to rapidly develop 'specific type' of applications. Ionic =  Cordova + Frontend SDK (Therefore, Ionic is preferred). IMO, Ionic is one of those technologies that is keeping Cordova alive.

Comment: Thank you for the information! How much angular JS do I need to learn for Ionic 1 and how different is TypeScript for Ionic 2?

Comment: Its easy to get started with ionic. But as your application grows, you will need deeper concepts of Angular to write enterprise level scalable codes (in JavaScript !). Therefore, Ionic 2 uses Angular 2 written in TypeScript with the goal of letting developers write scalable JS codes. You can check the difference between Ionic 1 and 2 @ www.ionicframework.com. (Its alot to write here and having conversation on comments is not encouraged in StackOverflow)

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is my understanding of the above scenario conceptually correct. If not, please clarify?

Yes, that's conceptually correct. This is how most apps work.

> 2. Is there any other way I can access/update data other than provided web API's?

You could always connect directly to the remote database from the Android app, but it is not recommended at all. The API provides you with the data you need, formats it for you, deals with security and abstracts the database for you. You're much better just using it.

> 3. Will I be using the web developer provided API to get data from server and also update data from the server? Does it work both ways. For example posting data on Facebook.

Yes, you retrieve the data from the server, display it in your app, and when you update something in your app, you post the changes on the server via the API to let the database know, via the same API (different routes).

> 4. Do I need to know any web programming in addition to access/update data using developer provided APIs? (I do not want to learn how to create web applications in addition to creating android applications at least at this time).

Not necessarily. You just have to understand how to work with JSON and the principles of a [REST API](https://developer.marklogic.com/try/rest/page2) (if the web developer followed the best practices when developing it).

> 5. I believe if I am asked to develop a hybrid android app using Cordova/Ionic, I would be accessing/updating data using my javascript builtin functions(not sure which one at this time) and pass my HTML, CSS and JavaScript to Ionic to wrap my app for a specific platform. Is my understanding accurate?

In that case, you would have to learn a little bit of both Android and Web programming. You have to have basic Android knowledge to work with Cordova / Ionic, and you need to have a good knowledge of Javascript / HTML / CSS to use the API from a webpage (which would then be wrapped in Cordova).

Comment: Great Thanks again!